# Correct way to get a Server Response Time from a URL in java?

Tags: java, selenium, server, webdriver

Correct way to get a Server Response Time from a URL in java?

1. i have x2 code examples, but not sure whether any of the following are correct?

**Code Example1:**

```
    public static void getResponseCode2(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
        pageLoad.start();
        huc.connect();
        pageLoad.stop();
        long pageLoadTime_ms = pageLoad.getTime();
        long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoadTime_ms / 1000;
        long pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder = (pageLoadTime_ms % 1000);
        System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + pageLoadTime_ms + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + "Seconds:" + pageLoadTime_Seconds + ", Remainder:"+ pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder);
        System.out.println("Status Code: " + huc.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

**Code Example2:**

```
public static void pingURL(String url, int timeout) {
        url = url.replaceFirst("^https", "http");
        try {
            StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
            pageLoad.start();
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            pageLoad.stop();
            long pageLoadTime_ms = pageLoad.getTime();
            long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoadTime_ms / 1000;
            long pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder = (pageLoadTime_ms % 1000);
            System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + pageLoadTime_ms + " milliseconds");
            System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + "Seconds:" + pageLoadTime_Seconds + ", Remainder:"+ pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    pingURL("https://www.buyagift.co.uk/", 30);
    getResponseCode2("https://www.buyagift.co.uk/");
}
```

[image]

Comment: In `pingURL` you are using HEAD instead of GET. So you are comparing Apples to Oranges.

Comment: ok @Fildor in your opinion what would be the best to get request for the HTTP or HTTPS header and wait for the response of a given url. (The response time is calculated from request to response.)